# Why one of virtual NICs called bond0?

Tags: ethernet

I just took over a very old network cluster(no documents and manual left) so I have to imagine the meaning of configuration by myself. Some of the servers' IP configure as following(when I issue ifconfig)

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>
        inet 10.1.237.11  netmask 255.255.255.192  broadcast 10.1.237.63
        ether 6c:90:af:68:5a:28  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)

bond0.901: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
        inet 147.146.67.13  netmask 255.255.255.240  broadcast 147.146.67.15
        ether 6c:90:af:68:5a:28  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)

bond0.901:1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>
        inet 147.185.211.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 147.185.211.255
        ether 6c:90:af:68:5a:28  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)

eth2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>
        ether 6c:90:af:68:5a:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

eth3: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>
        ether 6c:90:af:68:5a:28  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
```

From the same mac address, I can see there is only one NIC. I was told that bond0 for inner IP, bond0.901 for internet IP, bond0.901:1 for Anycast IP. So my question is that what do eth2 and eth3 for and why one of the virtual NIC called bond0, is there anything need to be bond together?

When I issued the command: lspci|grep Ether, I got the following:

```
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
01:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
09:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection (rev 01)
```

Does the above mean I have 10 physical Network cards please?

Comment: What does the output of `ifenslave -a` and `ip link show` and `ip addr show` look like?

Comment: `Does the above mean I have 10 physical Network cards please` - Sure looks like it.  Not sure which one of your interfaces are actually being used though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that `eth2`, and `eth3` are the physical devices that make up the `bond0` device.  See the master/slave flags.  But your system probably has 2 physical interfaces, these are being combined in some kind of fault tolerance, or link aggregation setup.  Try looking at the output of these tools which query the physical hardware `lspci | grep Ether`, or `lshw -class network`.  You probably will see at least 2 interfaces.

```
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>
eth2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>
eth3: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>
```

The contents of the file `/proc/net/bonding/bond0` would tell you more.

- Bonding docs https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bonding#ethernet-device-renaming

The `bond0.901` is a virtual device allowing for a tagged vlan 901 on bond0.

The `bond0.901:1` is just an secondary IP address for the `bond0.901` VLAN 901 interface.  This is not a real interface, or even a virtual one.  This 'interface' is just just a way for ifconfig to show you the second address. But it is a deprecated tool that can give you confusing output like this.  Use `ip addr`, or `ip link` instead.

Comment: Thank you! I appended description on my question about lspci results. And, you mentioned VLAN 901, where can I find the VLAN config please, what purpose of this VLAN please.

Comment: No idea what it is for, and no idea where it is configured.  There is no way for me to possibly know what it is for.  It is probably something local to your network environment. The location for the configuration is distro specific.  On Debian it might be under /etc/network/interfaces, but it might also be under /etc/systemd/network, or maybe one of a dozen other places.

Comment: one more question please, should the Switch has 901 Vlan configure, but I didn't find this Vlan in switch.

Comment: Modern Linux systems no longer even install `ifconfig` and `route` by default anymore, unless some legacy package gets installed that needs them. It's a good idea to get out of the habit of using them.